# How to set the backcolor of rich textbox?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, backcolor

Can anyone know how to set the backcolor of a richtextbox same as default backcolor of a form??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RichTextBox1.BackColor = Form1.BackColor
```

Or

```
RichTextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
```

Comment: Sorry SysDragon.. Now itz working. Problem from my code. i make readonly property true brfor set the back color. So sorry.. and Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the backcolor inside the form class code then you could simply write

```
rtb.BackColor = Me.BackColor
```

Comment: Not working with me. I am using Visual Studio 2008. after `rtb.BackColor =` it popup `color.color name`

Comment: Sorry Steve. Its working. Because mistake from my side. I make `rtb.Readonly=true` before set the back color. Now i changed my code and itz working....